# All the possible link generator with 64 digit key

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, numbers, pattern-matching

```
https://example.com/download-item/?downloadKey=ff0c4f7a18c826c022401eb97bf23fd3bc9f5e6d72d7577f561ada55c2f70567 ;
```

Here the key is 64 digit which is the combination of " Lowercase Characters " and " Numbers ".

If I want to generate all the possible 64 key links with " Lowercase Characters " and " Numbers " and which will end with " ; "  what should I do.

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example how you want the output

Comment: All possible 64-char keys with 0-9a-z is 16^64 keys which is an astronomical quantity. Please explain what you're trying to do in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

There's a reason we use hex strings of this length for keys, and that's to prevent people from doing exactly what you're trying to do, which is to abuse the system via effective brute forcing.

There is an astronomical quantity of possible strings (16<sup>64</sup>, to be exact), and you'll never be able to iterate through them all in your lifetime, or in anyone's lifetime.

Stop.

Use the service as intended, instead.

Comment: I want to use it for my own application to give access to my clients randomly.

Comment: @Bijubora You don't need to (and cannot) "generate all the possible 64 key links" to accomplish that.